# Using forward_as_tuple for sending an initializer list

Tags: c++11

Suppose the blow code:

```
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  map<int, std::array<int, 2>> a;

  a.emplace(piecewise_construct,
            forward_as_tuple(1),
            forward_as_tuple({1, 2}));

  return 0;
}
```

I want to emplace a `std::array` using an initializer list. But I got this error:

```
foo.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
foo.cc:13:36: error: too many arguments to function ‘std::tuple<_Elements&& ...> std::forward_as_tuple(_Elements&& ...) [with _Elements = {}]’
             forward_as_tuple({1, 2}));
                                ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h:63:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/map:61,
                 from foo.cc:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:869:5: note: declared here
     forward_as_tuple(_Elements&&... __args) noexcept
     ^
```

I know that there are many ways to implement this, but my question is about the wrong behavior of `forward_as_tuple` why it does not simply send the initializer list to the constructor of `std::array`?

I use c++11 and g++-4.8.4.

Comment: `forward_as_tuple` does not require a tuple as its inputs, it simply move all of its input as an rvalue reference and the constructor of [pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) is responsible to apply those references as a constructor parameters of each internal types.

Comment: `std::array` doesn't have a `std::initializer_list` constructor.

Comment: But I checked this externally and it works so I think it has this constructor. Also `std::array` is as an example and you can replace it with `std::vector` you get the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
forward_as_tuple({1, 2})
```

Braced initializers can't be perfect forwarded and deduced as `std::initializer_list`s like that, you need to explicitly convert them:

```
forward_as_tuple(std::initializer_list<int>{1,2})
```

However, although `std::array` can be initialized with braces due to aggregate initialization, it doesn't have a `std::initializer_list` constructor. If you really want this kind of initialization, you could use `std::vector`, but you might be better off just constructing the array and hoping that the compiler optimizes for you.